# Change background color for separate divs on focusout depending on current text input

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, this, contenteditable

Been thinking about this for many hours now but can't come up with a solution. I have about 5 divs with the same class: `<div contenteditable="true" class="change">`

When I click on a div, the first function makes the background color white.
When I leave the div, I want the color to change depending on what I wrote inside the div.

The good thing is that the color changes.
The bad thing is that when I afterwards click other divs and leave them, they receive the same color as the first div. Doesn't matter if I write nothing or if I write "yes", "no" or "maybe", the following divs still get the same color as first div when I leave them

Help! :(

```
    $(".change").focus(function() {

    var message = document.querySelector(".change").innerHTML;

        this.style.backgroundColor=("white");

    });



    $((".change") ).focusout(function() {

    var message = document.querySelector(".change").innerHTML;

    console.log(message);

    switch (message) {
      case 'yes':
        this.style.backgroundColor=("green");
        break;
      case 'no':
        this.style.backgroundColor=("red");
        break;
      case 'maybe':
        this.style.backgroundColor=("yellow");
        break;
      default:
        this.style.backgroundColor=("white");
        break;
}
});
```

Comment: Well for one thing your code has syntax errors. Neither the `focusout` callback nor the `switch` block get closed. Also, you have some unnecessary (though harmless) brackets e.g. `("white")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the **var message = document.querySelector(".change").innerHTML;** to **var message = $(this).text();**

```js
$(".change").focus(function() {

var message = document.querySelector(".change").innerHTML;

    this.style.backgroundColor=("white");

});



$((".change") ).focusout(function() {

var message = $(this).text();

switch (message) {
  case 'yes':
    this.style.backgroundColor=("green");
    break;
  case 'no':
    this.style.backgroundColor=("red");
    break;
  case 'maybe':
    this.style.backgroundColor=("yellow");
    break;
  default:
    this.style.backgroundColor=("white");
    break;
    
 }
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" class="change"></div>
<br />
<div contenteditable="true" class="change"></div>
<br />
<div contenteditable="true" class="change"></div>
<br />
<div contenteditable="true" class="change"></div>
<br />
<div contenteditable="true" class="change"></div>
<br />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your code you are always refering to the first found instance of `document.querySelector(".change").innerHtml`

Just change your code to this:

```
$(".change").focusout(function(event) {

    var message = event.target.value;

    console.log(message);

    switch (message) {
      case 'yes':
        this.style.backgroundColor=("green");
        break;
      case 'no':
        this.style.backgroundColor=("red");
        break;
      case 'maybe':
        this.style.backgroundColor=("yellow");
        break;
      default:
        this.style.backgroundColor=("white");
        break;
    }
});
```